# Excel not responding during long SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm looking for advice on how to avoid Excel not responding during a long SQL query.

If I run my VBA code with the data already in place, the execution takes less than one second. When running the code with the SQL query, execution time jumps up to about 11 seconds, which is the same amount of time it takes for the query to run in Microsofts SQL Server Management Studio.

While the code finishes without further problems every time, Excel turns unresponsive after about 6 seconds, showing a blank screen and a "Not responding" text. ScreenUpdating, Calculation, and Events are all disabled.

The user doesn't need to see anything happening while the macro is running, but I'd rather not have my colleagues see a blank screen with the "Not responding" text every time they run the macro.

Any general advice or reading on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think there is a method to prevent it from doing the whole Not Responding thing. One option is simply hide/minimize the window while it is working, or, display some sort of indicator that work is happening so users are distracted.

Comment: Instead of having Excel run the macro you can have another program run it or another excel application with having it hidden. Once you have the query, export it into a text or CSV file and have the macro check if it exists for whatever you're using it for. Otherwise since VBA doesn't support multi-threading in the Excel application itself it isn't possible for you to call the query and have the sheet not freeze.

Comment: One thing you might be able to do, is run the query asynchronously. Never tried it myself, but if you are using ADO, might work. Here's an article --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/190988/how-to-open-ado-recordsets-asynchronously-using-withevents

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll try your suggestions and see if I can improve performance or at least hide the application.